# Does Flutter named routes names matter?

Tags: flutter

Flutter's named routes are usually named as `/`, `/main`, `/main/second`. Do they actually have to have some sort of hierarchy with the `/` or any string is fine as the Framework just do string matching, so `/main/second` works as good as `main_second`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a convention. It is not required for you to name the routes with `/`, although the app's home route name is `/` by default. It's always good to follow these kind of conventions, but you can name your routes however you want, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Route names, by convention, use a path-like structure (for example, `'/a/b/c'`). The app's home page route is named `'/'` by default.

The MaterialApp can be created with a `Map<String, WidgetBuilder>` which maps from a route's name to a builder function that will create it. The MaterialApp uses this map to create a value for its navigator's `onGenerateRoute` callback.

read more from [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

Comment: Also in [those docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#using-named-navigator-routes), they complement `path/` usage with `snake_case` [in their example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#example) for even more granular naming: `.pushReplacementNamed('signup/choose_credentials')`